# Python : How do server come to know of network failure at the client side?

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, twisted

I am developing a chat based application in Python using `twisted` module. 
After a period of establishing the connection, let us assume, that the network connection fails at the client side.

How do I make sure that the server is notified about the network failure ?

Here is the code snippet( Server program) :

```
def main():
    """This runs the protocol on port 8000"""



    factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
    factory.protocol = Echo
    PortNo = 8000
    reactor.listenTCP(PortNo,factory)

    reactor.run()

# this only runs if the module was *not* imported
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.0.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IProtocol.html#connectionLost

But to be realy sure, you'd have to implement PING/PONG in the application. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812#section-3.7.2

Comment: When the network is down `connectionLost()` event is not called. Ping Pong is an idea which I am thinking right now. I am not sure how to handle ACKs from all the clients at the server side

Answer (score 0):

You have to (1) use a read timeout and (2) make sure you react appropriately to all error conditions when reading from or writing to the socket.

Comment: I have not been succesful though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have not been successful doing what? Not a useful comment.